# SSRS single bar-chart

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

Good day all,
Please am trying to create a SSRS report that looks like the image below

[image]

i have my table structure in this manner
[image]

**Please note the data are not in relation with the chart**
But all i could get as a result is a multiple bar chart. that resembles the image below.
[image]

Thanks in anticipations of your response

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your "Balance on COC" is negative. That's probably not just a chart visualization issue.

You can format the numbers on the y-axis to be more readable like they are in your first screenshot. Click on the Chart Axis and set the `LabelsFormat` property to `#,0;(#,0)`.

While numbers in the chart can have up to 16 digits, that is highly unreadable for most people. You might want to consider visualizing the numbers in Billions instead.

To get the labels on the x-axis you'll need to set that field as the `Category Group`. Then you can delete the legend area from the chart. You can also remove the "Axis Title" areas since they are not needed in this case. This will all make it look more polished like the other image.